# application : didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and viewDidLoad

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Going to decide where to put some of the initialization code.  There seems to be 2 places that we can usually choose : ...LaunchingWithOptions and viewDidLoad.

Wish to ask what are the tradeoffs in choosing between the two.

Also, are there other places that we should consider for this purpose ?

Also memory usage - if a view is being swapped out of memory during memory shortage, do we have to worry about initialization done in viewDidLoad ?  (Such as could the user loose any input during the process ...)

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to achieve. Do you have some more details? In general: place code in the class it belongs to.

Comment: i think this depends according to requirement, if the initialize is for complete app, better to do in launchingWithOptions. If only for the View, do in ViewDidLoad..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
```

belongs to AppDelegate. Usually Objects that are needed for life long as app itself are created and initialized here. [Here](http://teamtreehouse.com/library/ios-4-foundations/app-lifecycle-view-controllers/app-delegate-and-lifecycle/play) is Life Cycle of AppDelegate.

```
viewDidLoad
```

belongs to any [ViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Twitter/Reference/TWTweetSheetViewControllerClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010943), and Objects that are needed for life of the ViewController are created and initialized here. [Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/BasicViewControllers/BasicViewControllers.html) is Life Cycle of View Controller. Other methods to consider are

- `init`
- `initWithNibName: bundle:`

So it depends on the nature of the Objects.